# While on click on the span, how can we get the correct span name by using useRef()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting the  `nominee_name`  as the last `span` name even after clicking on the right span element. How can I get the correct span name from here  `<span className="countname" key={data.nomineename}  ref={nominee_name} onClick={handleClick}>{data.nomineename}</span>`.
The above span is iterated based on the data received.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios"; 

const Dashboard = props => {
    const [nominationCount, setNominationCount] = useState([]);
    const [nameText, setNameText] = useState("");
    let nominee_name = useRef(null);    
    const isMounted = useRef(false);
   
    

    useEffect(() => {
        isMounted.current = true;
        return () => isMounted.current = false;
    }, []);
    
  useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/nominationcount');
                if (isMounted.current) {
                    setNominationCount(res.data);
                    console.log("Nomination count data from server :" + res.data);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);


    const handleClick = () => {
        setNameText(nominee_name.current.outerText);
    }
 return (
  <div className="space_1 tile">
        <h3>Nominations Count</h3>
        <div className="grid-container">
            {
                    !nominationCount.length && (<div className="nonominationdata">No nominations count to display !</div>)
                }
                {
                    nominationCount.map(data => (
                         <div key={data.id}>
                                <div onClick={() => {setOpen(!open); }} className="count badge" >
                                    <span className="badgenumber" value={data.count} key={data.count}>{data.EmailCount}</span>
                                     <span className="countname" key={data.nomineename}  ref={nominee_name} onClick={handleClick}>{data.nomineename}</span>
                                </div>
                         </div>
                    ))
                }
        </div>
   </div>
   
    <Modal
         open={open}
         onClose={() => {
                    setOpen(false);
                }}
                className={classes.modal}>
                <form className={classes.form}>
                    <label className={classes.label}>Confirm winner {nameText}</label>
                    <input className={classes.submit} type="submit" value="Confirm" />
                </form>
            </Modal>
)
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "span name"? You're getting outerText of the last span element by your current code. Will you make your question more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure you want to use ref here.

Just pass the name into your click handler:

```
(
<span className="countname" key={data.nomineename}
    onClick={()=>setNameText(data.nomineename)}>{data.nomineename}</span>
)
```

Comment: Good point, some of the tutorials say to use useRef(), I will try that today evening and reply.

Comment: @soccerway bouncing data off the dom like that doesn’t really accomplish much. Save useRef for cases where you need a reference to the dom element. Besides you’d have to create a ref for every nominee. If you still want to read from the dom element, the click event passed to your callback should contain a reference to it.